# combine each element of two lists to a tuple in Python without using itertools packet

Tags: python, arraylist, tuples

I'm newbie, and I have two lists and want to combine them into a tuple, by random all possible element, **without using any packet such as itertools packet**.
Like this example:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = ["wow", 2]
```

and the output:

```
>>> new_tuple = (["a","wow"],["b","wow"],["c","wow"],["a",2],["b",2],["c",2])
```

Could you help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: a double for loop is enough for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 one-liner using list generator

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['wow', 2]
new_tuple = tuple([l1, l2] for l2 in list2 for l1 in list1)

print(new_tuple)
# (['a', 'wow'], ['b', 'wow'], ['c', 'wow'], ['a', 2], ['b', 2], ['c', 2])
```

Comment: the output is a list, but I need a tuple, so can I use tuple() there?

Comment: Yes, you can. Have updated the snippet as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools

```
import itertools
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = ["wow", 2]
c = tuple(itertools.product(list1, list2))
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `itertools` to make the permutation you request like the following should work for you:

```
import itertools
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = ["wow", 2]

all_combinations = []

list1_permutations = itertools.permutations(list1, len(list2))

for each_permutation in list1_permutations:
    zipped = zip(each_permutation, list2)
    all_combinations.append(list(zipped))

print(all_combinations)
```

Output looks like following:

````
[[('a', 'wow'), ('b', 2)], [('a', 'wow'), ('c', 2)], [('b', 'wow'), ('a', 2)], [('b', 'wow'), ('c', 2)], [('c', 'wow'), ('a', 2)], [('c', 'wow'), ('b', 2)]]```
````

Comment: thank you, if I want list3 is a tuple, can I use list3 = ([x, y] for x in list1 for y in list2)?

Comment: No as this would not give all the possibilities like you requested. But you can call the ```tuple(all_combinations)```

Comment: actually I don't want to use any packets but Numpy. can I still use for loop to add element into a tuple?

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

new_tuple = tuple([a, b] for b, a in product(list2, list1))
# (['a', 'wow'], ['b', 'wow'], ['c', 'wow'], ['a', 2], ['b', 2], ['c', 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
import random

list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = ["wow", 2]
new_tuple = ()
for x in (len(list1)+len(list2)):
  randInt = random.randint(0, len(list1))
  randInt2 = random.randint(0, len(list2))
  new_tuple += [list1[randInt], list2[randInt2]]
```

This is really simple python. Try the code out.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is basically a cartesian product. Try a list comprehension with itertools, such as:

```
import itertools
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = ["wow", 2]

new_tuple = [x for x in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to use itertools packet in my example.

Answer (score 0):

For converting 2 list to tuple, there is method [.zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp):

```
list(zip(list1, list2))
```

but it's only add elements in your case: (["a", "wow"], ["b", "2"]], so:

```
a = ("John", "Charles", "Mike")
b = ("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica")
```

---

```
tuples = []
def combineTuples(listA, listB):
  for i in range(len(listA)):
    for j in range(len(listB)):
        tuples.append((a[i], b[j]))
        
x = combineTuples(a, b)


print(tuples)
```

output:
[('John', 'Jenny'), ('John', 'Christy'), ('John', 'Monica'), ('Charles', 'Jenny'), ('Charles', 'Christy'), ('Charles', 'Monica'), ('Mike', 'Jenny'), ('Mike', 'Christy'), ('Mike', 'Monica')]

output with your data is idnetical, but without order.

[('a', 'wow'), ('a', 2), ('b', 'wow'), ('b', 2), ('c', 'wow'), ('c', 2)]